# How to create an imageView with shape circle and have a border?

Tags: android, android-imageview

I need to create an android app with having an `imageview` that need to be a circle (by croping squre image). I have used some coding from StackOverFlow but I've no idea to add a border to it.

**Coding below:**

```
package com.fidenz.fexceller.fexceller;

/**
 * Created by Chathu Hettiarachchi on 5/18/2015.
 */
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapShader;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.ColorFilter;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.graphics.Shader;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;

public class RoundedImg extends Drawable {
    private final Bitmap mBitmap;
    private final Paint mPaint;
    private final RectF mRectF;
    private final int mBitmapWidth;
    private final int mBitmapHeight;

    public RoundedImg(Bitmap bitmap) {
        mBitmap = bitmap;
        mRectF = new RectF();
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        final BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(bitmap, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
        mPaint.setShader(shader);

        mBitmapWidth = mBitmap.getWidth();
        mBitmapHeight = mBitmap.getHeight();
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawOval(mRectF, mPaint);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBoundsChange(Rect bounds) {
        super.onBoundsChange(bounds);
        mRectF.set(bounds);
    }

    @Override
    public void setAlpha(int alpha) {
        if (mPaint.getAlpha() != alpha) {
            mPaint.setAlpha(alpha);
            invalidateSelf();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter cf) {
        mPaint.setColorFilter(cf);
    }

    @Override
    public int getOpacity() {
        return PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
    }

    @Override
    public int getIntrinsicWidth() {
        return mBitmapWidth;
    }

    @Override
    public int getIntrinsicHeight() {
        return mBitmapHeight;
    }

    public void setAntiAlias(boolean aa) {
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(aa);
        invalidateSelf();
    }

    @Override
    public void setFilterBitmap(boolean filter) {
        mPaint.setFilterBitmap(filter);
        invalidateSelf();
    }

    @Override
    public void setDither(boolean dither) {
        mPaint.setDither(dither);
        invalidateSelf();
    }

    public Bitmap getBitmap() {
        return mBitmap;
    }

}
```

And I call image using this:

```
ImageView profilePic;
RoundedImg roundedImage,ring;

profilePic = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img_home_profile_pic);

        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.no_image);
        roundedImage = new RoundedImg(bm);
        profilePic.setImageDrawable(roundedImage);
```

Comment: see this link https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView

Comment: Please refer below link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17655264/how-to-add-a-shadow-and-a-border-on-circular-imageview-android

Comment: possibly the mirror of this
[Create Circlular ImageView with Border][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30161450/how-to-create-drawable-circle-with-below-requirement/30161771#30161771

Comment: @AngadTiwari & Hasmukh Barochiya, please vote to close as duplicate instead of pasting the link to the dupe in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Try with something like this:

```
ImageView profilePic;
RoundedImg roundedImage,ring;

Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.no_image);
Bitmap withBorder = addBlackBorder(bm, 5);
roundedImage = new RoundedImg(withBorder);
profilePic.setImageDrawable(roundedImage);

 private Bitmap addBlackBorder(Bitmap bmp, int borderSize) {
    Bitmap bmpWithBorder = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp.getWidth() + borderSize * 2, bmp.getHeight() + borderSize * 2, bmp.getConfig());
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmpWithBorder);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, borderSize, borderSize, null);
    return bmpWithBorder;
}
```

Comment: This is good. But I think he should create the border after rounding the picture, not before. This way the border will be cropped to a rounded image.

Comment: yes, maybe you are right. So maybe this one could be helpful https://github.com/Pkmmte/CircularImageView

Comment: He could just draw another oval before the bitmap using your code. But that could be helpful as well.